# EF 4 connection string metadata

Tags: entity-framework, connection-string

I've ran into an extremely annoying problem with Entity Framework 4. I basically moved the entity framework EDMX file from one assembly to another, but when my connection strings metadata gets resolved at run time something still inserts the old DLL name into the metadata of the connection string. The connection string is currently defined as

```
<add name="HNMTEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Data.HNMTModel.csdl|res://*/Data.HNMTModel.ssdl|res://*/Data.HNMTModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=machine\Database;initial catalog=HN18;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

But in the metadata portion of it, the * is replaced with the old DLL name rather than the new one. I've read a few posts on this and have tried moving the connection string to the application app.config file and deleting and recreating the model but it still doesn't work and the name of the old DLL gets inserted into the connection string.

Does anyone know a way around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, we were passing in a hardcoded DLL name in the code :(